# How do I access rdio API?

Tags: json, ajax, api, rdio

This is what I have:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'get',
  url: 'https://services.rdio.com/api/1/',
  dataType: "JSONP",
  method: 'getTopCharts'
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

I'm not very good with using APIs.  I would like to get the top charts in json format.  Right now this is what I see in the console with an x beside it:

https://services.rdio.com/api/1/?method=getTopCharts&callback=jQuery21406818272015079856_1447092130458&_=1447092130459

Do I need to use an API key?  In the docs it says 
does not require user authentication.  So how do I get my list?

Answer (score 0):

All Rdio API requests must use the POST method and contain an access token. Checkout the [Rdio API Overview](http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/overview/). Rdio doesn't support JSONP, but CORS is supported. Using jQuery, the request would look like:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://services.rdio.com/api/1/get",
  data: {
    method: "get",
    keys: "r139688",
    access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN"
  }
})
```

You'll need to fill-in your own access token. Checkout the [OAuth 2.0 documentation](http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/oauth2/index/) for how to generate an access token.

Comment: I read the doc, I'm still confused on how I would generate an access token.